# Why doesn't onClick handler work for anchor elements created with React.createElement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create an anchor element via [React.createElement](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.createelement), but the `onClick` handler doesn't get invoked when the anchor is clicked. Why is this?

```
React.createElement('a', {
  className: 'test',
  href: '#',
  onClick: () => {
    console.log(`Link has been clicked`)
  },
}, 'Test')
```

When clicking an anchor element created like this, nothing is printed so the `onClick` handler isn't invoked.

Even though my custom click handler (`onClick`) isn't invoked, the browser does process the link being clicked, since it changes the page hash as the link is clicked (the link's URL being `#`).

If I change the element type to e.g. `button`, the custom `onClick` callback works as expected, so the issue is specific to the `a` element type.

I'm using React version 0.14.3.

Comment: Admittedly guessing but if it were me I'd try `onclick` instead of `onClick`. *edit* apparently wrong :)

Comment: If you add some content so there’s anything to click on at all, [it works for me.](https://jsfiddle.net/hzy14adx/)

Comment: @icktoofay I forgot to add to the example, but I did that now and have tested that it makes no difference for me. I am using Chrome Version 49.0.2593.0 dev (64-bit).

Comment: @icktoofay I can see that your example works though, which is strange. Maybe there's something to do with my app that causes this. It doesn't happen for other element types though, e.g. button.

Comment: If you can reduce your application down to a minimal amount of complete, runnable code that still demonstrates the problem, that would be helpful. (I understand that may be a large undertaking, but unfortunately I think it might be necessary to see the problem before knowing how to fix it.)

Comment: @icktoofay I wish someone with knowledge of React's implementation could explain what might be going on here. Reducing to a reproducible case may indeed prove to be too large of an undertaking. I would probably prefer if I could actively debug React myself.

Comment: @aknuds1 It's almost certainly something specific to your app or page. Is it possible some other code is doing a `stopPropagation` to prevent the event from making it to the link? A jQuery plugin, router implementation, etc?

Comment: @MichelleTilley It's really difficult to tell. It's specific to the `a` element type. All I have to do is replace the `a` tag with `button`, and `onClick` works. The `a` element does handle the click, it's just not invoking my custom handler. I can tell because the browser follows the link (`#`) when I click it.

Comment: So I would really like a way to debug React itself, to figure out why my custom click handler isn't used.

Comment: What version of React are you using?

Comment: @christopher 0.14.3.

Comment: @aknuds1 I had similar issues with 13, 0.13.* so I moved up. Have you tried using the Chrome React plugin to see if React is attaching an event handler to the element?

Comment: @christopher How do I tell using the plugin? I have already installed it.

Comment: @christopher The React plugin actually says that an `onClick` handler is installed for the `a` element, but it doesn't fire. If I remove the `onClick` handler from the code, the React plugin correspondingly reports that the element has no `onClick` handler so it looks as if my handler is actually installed.

Comment: what if you set the `href="?blah"` then be sure to set a `return false` for the onclick.  Might work.

Comment: @Clayton I tried. The browser URL changes to add `?blah` at the end, that's all.

Comment: what if you assign the onClick handler after creating the element?  What about trying onClickCapture (just to see if it works)?

Comment: @Clayton `onClickCapture` makes no difference. How do I assign the handler after creating the element?

Comment: I don't know anything about React haha but according to Google it looks like you can use addEventListener('onClick(??)', function(){}).  I'm assuming createElement returns an object you can call that method on.  And is the ` () => ` something from JSX?

Comment: @Clayton `() =>` is ECMAScript 2015. I doubt I can call `addEventListener` on a React virtual DOM element.

Comment: Is the behavior the same in all browsers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99014/discussion-between-aknuds1-and-clayton).